# Can I change the USB device name of Arduino?

Tags: serial, usb

I have several Arduinos connected to my Windows PC, and they appear as follows:

> COM7 (Arduino Uno)
>   COM11 (Arduino Uno)
>   COM13 (Arduino Uno)

So there's no way to tell which is which, and when I want to upload a sketch to one, I have to unplug the others to make sure my code goes to the right one.

Is there a way to change the "Arduino Uno" description?

(I found a similar question but that was about Mac specifically).

Comment: You'll have to [change the firmware](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/hardware/arduino/avr/firmwares/atmegaxxu2/arduino-usbserial/Descriptors.c#L220) on the usb to serial chip (atmega16u2)

Comment: And modify the driver to include the new name.

Comment: Here is the current link from @Gerben's Comment https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/1.8.1/firmwares/atmegaxxu2/arduino-usbserial/Descriptors.c#L220

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to change the software on the Arduino USB chip itself, and you may need to modify the drivers for the Arduino USB interface on the computer side.  It's not trivial, and probably not worth it.

However, Windows attempts to use the same serial port for the same devices in the same USB positions, so if you figure out which is which (blinking the LED at different frequencies) then you can mark the USB port itself with the com number that Windows uses when you plug an arduino into it.

If you use a hub, and you move that hub to a different port, the com numbers will change, but if you keep it in the same port, then it too will try to have them match what they have been in the past.

It's an annoyance, but it's a design decision by arduino.cc.  The old FTDI chips kept their assigned com port numbers because they have individual serial numbers and windows would attempt to reassign the same com port to the same chip each time it was plugged in, regardless of its location.  When Arduino.cc moved to a programmed MCU for the USB interface, they chose not to provide USB serial numbers, and thus windows has little option but to try to keep things straight by determining the location in the USB hierarchy that the device is connected, and try to keep com port assignments the same using that method.

Comment: "... they chose not to provide USB serial numbers ..." Oh wow. Was any rationale ever given for this?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I've not seen any information from them on this issue.  They probably don't think it's important (the majority of users don't need it) and it does increase the cost as they not only have to program the chips individually, but track arduino serial numbers in some sort of coordinated fashion to avoid duplication. Given the number of knock-offs in addition to the licensed variants, it's a problem not worth tackling without good reason.

Answer (score 0):

I have never tried it, but I suspect using zadig might work;
http://zadig.akeo.ie/

It lets you pick the driver and name for WinUSB and LibUSB devices.  Uninstall any existing driver first. And remember to pick the driver you wish to use when it asks. Also it is not real apparent, but you can edit the name of the device as it installs the driver.

Let us know if it works